# Inserting text from specific cells into the newName in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a code that will save a copy of a file with a new name based on text in Cells D1 and D2 from the active sheet of a workbook. I can't seemingly find a way to make it so the cells determine the new file name. I can only find codes that use a static name I type into the code. Is there anyway of making this code into one that will use the range of cells as the new name? if needed the full name of the current (base) file is "G:\PRODUCTION\Service\CARBIDE SHARPENING CHECK IN SHEET.xlsm"

To clarify if cells D1 and D2 on this sheet say "04-29-22" and "Example" the file should save with a name of "04-29-22 Example". For reference of what my end goal is, and I am very new to VBA.

```
Sub SaveAs_Ex1()

Dim newName As String
newName = Range("D1:D2")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("D1:D2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Not tested, maybe try `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("D1").value & " " & range("D2").value`

Comment: would you also by chance know how I can change the file path it saves the new files to, so I can make it save them in a specific drive folder?

Comment: AJ, please try : `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\test\" & Range("D1").value & " " & range("D2").value, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`. It will save the file as xlsm in drive D, folder test.